# Access data from external container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have some docker images running like below:

```
77beec19859a        nginx:latest                "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp                       dockerisedphp_web_1
d48461d800e0        php:fpm                     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   9 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        9000/tcp                                   dockerisedphp_php_1
a6ed456a4cc2        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       sc-phpmyadmin
9e0dda76c110        firewatchdocker_webserver   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   7.4.x-webserver
beba7cb1ee14        firewatchdocker_mysql       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp          mysql
000e0f21d46e        redis:latest                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                     sc-redis
```

The problem is: My PHP script need to access the data on the mysql inside the `mysql` container from the container `dockerisedphp_web_1`.

This kind of data exchange between containers is possible?

Actually I'm using the docker-compose to bring all up.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) says: "Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name."

Comment: @Alexander, not working the mysql port is 3306, when I ask for the php to connect got unable to connect.

Comment: I think, it's necessary to clarify the question: show your docker-compose file snippet and connection sting that is used. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do something with the data, and you don't need it on the host, you can use [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

If you want to copy it to the host, or copy data from the host into a container, you can use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

You can use `docker exec` to run mysql client inside the mysql container, write the results to a file, and then use `docker cp` to copy the output to the host.

Or you can just do something like `docker exec mysql-container-name mysql mysql-args > output` on the host.